# MySql php data display in tables

Tags: php, mysql, word-wrap, tablerow

I am doing a simple set of PHP scripts to edit and return MySQL records from a web site.
Everything works fine but there is a cosmetic that I just cannot seem to correct.
I presume being very rusty I am missing something obvious - I have tried everything I can think of though.
The content of field  ADDTEXT can be fairly large and i would like to word wrap it all into the table cell.  This script  truncates it when a single line length is exceeded.
 And yes I know I should be using mysqli_... but I am deaeling with that !

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Form Edit Data</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>EDIT NEWS ITEM</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
      <table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
      <?


   $id=$_GET['id'];

  include "D***************.uk\public_html\html\ConnectDB.php";//database connection

      $order = "SELECT * FROM st¬¬¬¬¬¬¬ where TYPE = '".$id."'";


      $result = mysql_query($order);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
      <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[TITLE]"?>">
        <tr>       
          <td>Item Title</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="title"
        value="<? echo "$row[TITLE]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>Item Text</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="text" 
          value="<? echo "$row[ADDTEXT]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit"
          name="submit value" value="Edit">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: SQL injection alert. Be careful!

Comment: You should consider using `mysqli_` or PDO. `mysql_` functions have been deprecated and will no longer be supported in the near future, and contains security risks due to susceptibility to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to textarea field.

```
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $row['ADDTEXT'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: I think I am overlooking something glaringly obvious - that doesnt seem to work either.  I have removed everything down to the basics and it still doesnt seem to go.

Comment: Ah ha got it - I hadnt twigged that textarea could not be an input.   Just need to check that the name goes forward with the submit and all is clear - Thanks gentlemen

Comment: No problem, thumb up if this answer was useful :-). Cheers.

Comment: I simply had forgotten that there could be other "inputs" in a form apart from "<input " tag.  Works fine with textarea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try it
<html>
      <head>
      <title>Form Edit Data</title>
      </head>

      <body>
      <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td align=center>EDIT NEWS ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
          <table style="width:100%">
       <tr><td>
          <?


       $id=$_GET['id'];

      include "D***************.uk\public_html\html\ConnectDB.php";//database connection

          $order = "SELECT * FROM st¬¬¬¬¬¬¬ where TYPE = '".$id."'";
     $result = mysql_query($order);
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      ?>
          <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['TITLE']?>">
            <tr>       
              <td>Item Title</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="title"
            value="<?php echo $row['TITLE']?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>Item Text</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="text" 
              value="<?php echo $row['ADDTEXT']?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <input type="submit"
              name="submit value" value="Edit">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </form>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for SQL injection note - the script given is actually just a subset for demonstration of the problem. The working script is protected.

Comment: Tried Hara's version with no different result

Comment: Also took out the MySQL bit and just set some fixed text entries with same result.  Very strange